# :last-child effects all img tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this is the first time posting a question so i hope i am doing this right. What i want to do, is have my last child in my wrapper div to not margin to the right.

```css
.wrapper img,
video {
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.wrapper img,
video:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="cat.jpg">
  <video>
    <source src="cats.mp4">
    </video>
  <img src="morecats.jpg">
  <video>
    <source src="meow.mp4">
    </video>
  <img src="garfield.jpg">
</div>
```

The problem here, is that every img tag in the div will now have margin-right:0;
 . I hope someone understands my question and can help me out.

Note: I'm not allowed to use languages other than HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add :last-child to the img too.

```
.wrapper img:last-child, .wrapper video:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: ... and .wrapper to video as well (assuming this should apply to videos inside that wrapper only.)

Answer (score 0):

To remove `margin-right: 0;` from last child in the div, you can do this:

```
.wrapper img:not(:last-child),
    video:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```css
.wrapper img,
video {
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.wrapper img:not(:last-child),
video:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="cat.jpg">
  <video>
    <source src="cats.mp4">
    </video>
  <img src="morecats.jpg">
  <video>
    <source src="meow.mp4">
    </video>
  <img src="garfield.jpg">
</div>
```